# Ants moving from vertex to vertex on a polyhedron

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

On a regular polyhedron, there is one ant on each vertex. In one round, every ant walks to an adjacent vertex, each adjacent vertex with equal probability. Let $P(r)$ be probability that after ***r*** rounds, each vertex still has exactly one ant.

> Does $P(r)$ converge as ***r*** tends to infinity?
>
> How does the function behave? Is it monotonic?

For example, $P(1)$ of tetrahedron is $\frac{1}{9}$; $P(1)$ of octahedron is $\frac{5}{256}$.

Comment: Seems kinda related to graphs and flow?

Comment: The question has already been expertly answered; since there are only five regular polyhedra, it might be worthwhile to compare the limiting values of the probability explicitly. Tetrahedron: $4!/4^4=0.09375$; octahedron: $6!/6^6\approx0.01543$; cube: $(4!)^2/4^8=(4!/4^4)\approx0.008789$, the square of the value for the tetrahedron; dodecahedron: $12!/12^{12}\approx5.372\cdot10^{-5}$; icosahedron: $20!/20^{20}\approx2.320\cdot10^{-8}$.

Comment: The icosahedron and dodecahedron should be reversed.  "Icosa" means 20 but that's faces; the icosahedron has only 12 vertices hence a higher probability than the 20-vertex docecahedron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For polyhedra where there is a face with an odd number of vertices, like the triangular faces of an octahedron, you don't need the full Markov chain treatment to see what happens.  Just consider the nature of the "limiting" distribution.  Say it's the version of the problem with an octahedron (6 vertices). Over many shifts each ant has an equal probability of occupying any vertex so that there are $6^6$ equally probable ant-vertex permutations.  Out of these, $6!$ permutations have each ant on a different vertex so your converged value of $P(r)$ is $6!/6^6=5/324=0.0154...$ .  Clearly for $n$ vertices the converged value of $P(r)$ is $n!/n^n$, if we have odd-vertex faces.

As pointed out in the comments (Josh B.), this approach fails when the faces all have an even number of vertices, for then the vertices get split into two alternant groups and the convergence to a random distribution is not achieved.

Ross Millikan suggests a method to deal with this alternant case.  We label one set of alternant vertices A and the other set B.  We start with equal numbers of ants on A vertices and ants on B vertices ($n/2$ apiece) to have any chance of getting all ants on separate vertices.  If this constraint is satisfied, then in the limiting case we have a probability of $((n/2)!)/((n/2)^{n/2})$ for ants being equally distributed on the A vertices, and an equal factor for the B vertices.  This gives a total probability $P(\infty)=((n/2)!)^2/((n/2)^n)$ for the alternant case.  For a cube with all faces having four vertices and $n=8$, the result is $(4!)^2/(4^8)=9/1024=0.008789...$ .

Comment: This doesn't work with the cube, as you can partition the vertices into two sets such that an ant must move from one set to the other.

Comment: So can the Markov chain approach work? Do we get a degenerate matrix and we can't pick out a unique eigenvector?

Comment: I think the cube works this way, too.  Just divide the vertices into two groups of $4$ that are alternating.  The four ants in one group are independent of the four in the other group.  You need each group to be on different vertices, so the chance for the cube is $\frac {(4!)^2}{(4^4)^2}=\frac 9{1024}\approx 0.008789$

Comment: I agree @ross.  Please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: I think this is better as a comment to yours because it is your method.  If you want to edit it in, that is fine with me.

Comment: @OscarLanzi can you explain why 'even' faces don't work(cube for example) in more detail? I just graduated from middle school.

Comment: @V.Chen  Find a simpler case to play with. Consider a square instead of a cube. Can adjacent ants ever end up on the same vertex? Remembering that the ants all move at the same time, and that they must move. Why not? Then try to generalize to a cube.

Comment: @V.Chen:  you can color the vertices of a cube black and white with every black vertex connected to white vertices and vice versa.  The four ants that start on black vertices will be on white vertices after an odd number of moves and on black vertices after an even number of moves.  The argument that each ant has an equal chance to be on any given vertex after a long time fails.  My fix is to claim that each one has an equal chance to be on one of the four vertices of the proper color.

Answer (score 4):

You have a Markov chain with the states being the distribution of numbers of ants on each vertex.  Certainly the probability of each distribution will converge, so specifically $P(r)$ will converge to something.  If you work out the transition probabilities between all the states you can compute the equilibrium distribution.  A tetrahedron is quite simple because the vertices are all connected so all we care about is the list of numbers at each vertex.  You can make a matrix of probabilities, like $(4,0,0,0)$ goes to $(4,0,0,0)$ with probability $3/81$, to $(3,1,0,0)$ with probability $24/81$, to $(2,2,0,0)$ with probability $18/81$ and to $(2,1,1,0)$ with probability $36/81$.  Make the whole matrix, find the dominant eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector and you will have the limiting distribution.  You can then multiply the matrix by the starting probability of $1$ in $(1,1,1,1)$ and see if the probability ever decreases.

Comment: See my answer and the comments to it.  We seem to have a degeneracy when all faces of the polyhedron have an even number of vertices, like a cube.  Can, and how can, this approach work in such a case?